# Network manager - issues with DNS for VPN

Tags: networking, debian

I work on a Debian 11 system with KDE and use network manager to handle the network connections: the normal LAN and a VPN. These are my configs:

```
# cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

# plasmashell -v
plasmashell 5.20.5

# nmcli -v
nmcli tool, version 1.30.6
```

Before I connect to the VPN, my resolv.conf looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And when I'm connected to the VPN:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fakecompany.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.50.9
```

This may be how it is designed to work, but it means that name lookups on the company DNS tend to fail, because our internal hostnames are not on the open internet, of course. What I have to live with atm is to manually edit `resolv.conf`, and it is a bit tedious.

Is there a way to make network manager simply replace the original?

Answer (score 1):

Set the connection's `ipv4.dns-priority` and `ipv6.dns-priority` parameters to a *negative* value (see the 'nm-settings' manual page).

```
nmcli con modify "My Little VPN" ipv4.dns-priority -100
nmcli con modify "My Little VPN" ipv6.dns-priority -100
```

Alternatively: Enable the systemd-resolved service; this should cause resolv.conf to point to `127.0.0.53` only, with `resolvectl` being used to control DNS configuration. (You might need to manually change the resolv.conf symlink.) This has the advantage of supporting multiple sets of DNS servers simultaneously – your company's DNS would be used for the suffixes obtained from the VPN, while 8.8.8.8 would be used for everything else.

```
systemctl enable --now systemd-resolved

# Swap resolv.conf and restart both services for a clean state
ln -bvnsf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
systemctl restart systemd-resolved NetworkManager

# Check status
resolvectl

# Bring up VPN, check status again
nmcli con up "My Little VPN"
resolvectl
resolvectl query foo.mycompany.com
```